# Initializing strings in C++

Tags: c++, string, initialization

So, this question will probably be shot down instantly, but, I recently started learning C++, and I noticed that there is a line of code that is:

```
#include <string>
```

Does this mean that if I had a program that stated:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string foo = "test";
    cout << foo;
}
```

would it not compile correctly? And if so, would that mean that Strings have to be, in a more java-y way of saying it, "imported"? If there are any problems with the code below please let me know. Sorry if this was a bad question.

Comment: Have you tried compiling it?

Comment: What is `#includes`?

Comment: Please try compiling it on your own. I compiled it on eclipse and encountered no error. PS, I have suggested an edit to your post. Use `#include`, not `#includes`. Also, please use `using namespace std;` or `std::`

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj You did not compile the code that was posted.  It is riddled with errors.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Please check my editted comment

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj  You are changing the OP's question.  The code posted does *not* compile correctly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That would compile correctly when my edit to his post is accepted by peers. Then I believe my answer would make much more sense.

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj [It compiles correctly](http://rextester.com/UXZ22090)?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Strangely enough, it does compile correctly in Eclipse C++  although I believe you should have to add `#include <string>` which I have not...

Comment: Eclipse is not a C++ compiler -- it is a development environment that happens to invoke your C++ compiler (which is probably g++).

Comment: Yes, indeed, it is g++. Even when I add a `cin` statement, it works fine for me

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie As you can see, now that the post is editted, my coments make perfect sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize a string by firstly `#include<string>` and then `std::string nameofstring`.
Edit: for `cout` you also have to use `std::cout` if you don't want to use namespaces.

Comment: you need to use `<string>` not `<string.h>`

Comment: Depends on the compiler being used. `<string.h>` is used in old compilers like Turbo C++

Comment: If i used <code>using namespace std;</code> would I be able to get rid of the std:: in std::string?

Comment: Yes, you would though that is not recommended as sometimes you use multiple `namespace`s

Comment: Using statements like `using std::string;` `using std::cout;`, etc would be safer than using a single `using namespace std;` statement.

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj This is opinion based. In this program it wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @PaulKramme Yes indeed, it is. I am sorry I did not realize.

Answer (score 1):

would it not compile correctly? May or may not. It is an undefined behavior.

In C++, declaration should precede definitions and usage. So, if you are using a definition, compiler expects you to declare somewhere before you are using it.

General convention is to include all declarations inside a header file, and that is true for all types that are shipped with the standard library. If you are planning to use one of the standard library types, templates, constants or values, you should know from where that declaration would be present and include it in your translation unit failing which it would be an undefined behavior.

Comment: I recently edited the code shown above. The previous version had no `using namespace std;` and was using `#includes`. Thus, it would not compile correctly.

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj: I believe you did the wrong thing of editing it. This has invalidated the original question and nevertheless made the answers irrelevant.

Comment: I did not know that such a great audience would come before my edit was approved. I am extremely sorry for all inconvenience caused heretofore.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a mistake to equate `#include` with java's import: if you import a module, you have all of it's definitions and code. `#include`ing something doesn't guarantee you have everything. In C++ headers are often used to share *definitions* between modules, so that `b.cpp` knows how large `class A` is from `a.cpp`, and so forth. The implementation is stored in separate, compiled, binary files or libraries, and `#include` doesn't automatically associate those with your project.

Consider the following:

```
// foo.h
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
};

// foo.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"
Foo::Foo() {
    std::cout << "hello\n";
}
```

"foo.h" contains the *declaration* of Foo, but it is lacking the functionality. If I now write another file:

```
// bar.cpp
#include "foo.h"

int main() {
    Foo f;
}
```

this compiles fine. But when it gets to the linking stage it will complain that I don't have the *definition* (implementation) of `Foo::Foo()`. You have to explicitly link the two binaries together to produce an executable. With GCC/Clang that would be

```
g++ -Wall foo.cpp bar.cpp
```

Or if you've turned "foo" into a library:

```
g++ -Wall bar.cpp -lfoo
```

With an IDE like Eclipse of Visual Studio, you would have to manually inform the project of the need to include the additional cpp file / object file / library.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the originally shown code would not compile no matter what was `#include`d. That's because the class name is `std::string`, and not `string`. As you've eventually figured out, and updated your question with.

Each class, or template, or any other resource that's defined by the C++ library requires an appropriate standard header file to be `#include`d. Although including a particular header file could also, indirectly, include some other ones, so you end up getting those header files' contents "for free", this would be relying on a compiler-specific feature. When I regularly update my code and rebase against a newer version of `gcc` I often find some bits, here and there, that are now missing an explicit `#include` of the right header file, because, unknowingly, I missed it, but the previous compiler version's header files ended up pulling it in anyway.

So, after fixing the class name to `std::string` you may find out that the resulting code does or does not compile. If it does compile, it's only due to the good graces of your specific compiler's headers, and it may not be compilable by other compilers, or by newer versions of the same compiler you are using.

P.S. You should [avoid `using namespace std;`, this is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice). As you've started learning C++, now would be the best opportunity to avoid acquiring bad programming habits.